# How display selected (value is set to another option) option in Select2 using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a hidden input to save row_id. Also I have a Button that onclick should change selected option in select2 in my form.
My select looks like:

```
<select class="select2" id="my_select">
  <option value='0'>row_id_0</option>
  <option value='1'>row_id_1</option>
  <option value='2'>row_id_2</option>
</select>
```

My button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Submit()"> Submit </button>
```

My hidden input:
`<input type="hidden" id="InputRow" name="InputRow" value=""/>`

Function Submit():

```
function Submit() {
  var row_id = $('#InputRow').val();

  if (row_id)
  {
    

    // tried, but doesn't work
    //var select = document.getElementById('my_select');
    //select.value = row_id.toString();


    // also tried, but it only changes value and I can see that correct option in select is lighted
    // but on form it is still 'row_id_0' (first option in select)
    //document.getElementById('my_select').value = row_id;
    //document.getElementById('my_select').selected = true;

    // also tried this. Result was the same (didn't work)
    //$('#my_select').val(row_id);
  }
}
```

By default I have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmeXl.png)

After click on Submit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef1Mw.png)

You can see, that select think `row_id_2` is select, but it still display `row_id_0`

Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow. Everything I tried is above

Comment: Correct me if I wrong. You trying to update 'Select' value with 'Input' value?

Comment: Yes, I want my select show correct option (the same id as I have in my hidden input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To programmatically select an option/item for a Select2 control, use the jQuery.val() method:

Select the option with a value of '1' `$('#my_select').val('1');`.

Notify any JS components that the value changed `$('#my_select').trigger('change');`.

See more in [select2](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options), [jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/%5D) and [jQuery.trigger('change')](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```js
$('#my_select').select2();

function Submit() {
  var row_id = $('#InputRow').val();

  if (row_id)
  {
    $('#my_select').val(row_id);
    $('#my_select').trigger('change');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" id="my_select" style="width: 150px;">
  <option value='0'>row_id_0</option>
  <option value='1'>row_id_1</option>
  <option value='2'>row_id_2</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Submit()"> Submit </button>
<input type="hidden" id="InputRow" name="InputRow" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign value to `<select>` element like so

```js
function updateSelect () {
  const selectEl = document.getElementById("my-select")
  const inputEl = document.getElementById("my-input")
  
  selectEl.value = inputEl.value
}
```

```html
<select name="rows" id="my-select">
  <option value="row-1">Row 1</option>
  <option value="row-2">Row 2</option>
  <option value="row-3">Row 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="my-input">

<button onclick="updateSelect()">Update</button>
```

Note, that if you type and submit some value which not presented inside `select` element, then select will display nothing, so you only can submit values like 'row-1' 'row-2' 'row-3' as per example above.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: It doesn't get it. It give the same problem, correct line is lighted in select bar but it doesn't dicplay correct line as selected one.